# Convert char buffer to hex and write into a file (VC++)

Tags: c++

I have two DWORD. One is a pointer to a section of memory that I have to read and the other is the message length.
I need to copy that "buffer" and save it to a file in hexadecimal. In addition I have to save other data.
So far I have:

```
    ofstream logFile;
logFile.open("log.txt");
int coutSend = 0;
int countRecv = 0;
void SavePacket(DWORD MemoryPointer, DWORD BufferLength, bool Direction)
{
    if (Direction == 0) {
        countSend++;
    }
    else
    {
        countRecv++;
    }

    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    char * pMemory= reinterpret_cast<char*>(MemoryPointer);
    char * msg= new char[BufferLength];
    strcpy_s(msg, BufferLength, pMemory);
    logFile << ltm->tm_hour << ":" << ltm->tm_min << ":" << ltm->tm_sec << "," << Direction << "," << hex << msg << endl;
}
```

So if I logFile << pMemory writes the entire message as ascii but I need to write it as hexadecimal.

Comment: use a for loop and print each character separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides writing the output in hexadecimal, you have a major memory leak. You're malloc-ing a buffer, that you're not free-ing.

First of all, you are uselessly copying the pointer into the malloced buffer, for no apparent purpose whatsoever. Your original `pMemory` pointer will do just as well of a job of writing out the output as the `msg` copy. So, the first step is to get rid of allocating `msg` and copying the memory, for no useful purpose, and fixing the memory leak that way.

Now, as far as writing hexadecimal, use the `std::hex` and `std::setw(2)` manipulators, and write out the character buffer one byte at a time, using a loop.

```
while (bufferLength)
{
    logFile << std::hex << std::setw(2) << (int)(unsigned char)*pMemory;
    ++pMemory;
    --bufferLength;
}
```